# Django - emulating searching/filtering of admin interface

Tags: django, admin

I have a simple Django view that displays a list of objects.  I want users to be able to search/filter/sort, etc. the list of objects.  The way the admin interface does it by default (with all of those enabled) is exactly what I'm looking for.

Is there any easy way to do this in Django?  Or is there some third-party plugin to do it for me?  Or am I stuck writing all of the code by hand?

I feel like this is a problem that many others must have faced before, so what's the easiest (and least redundant) way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either sort your objects via Javascript, or you can sort your objects on the server.

The javascript is limiting because in the case of a large number of objects that are paginated, you will only be able to sort what is on the current page.

The easiest way is to sort your records on the server side, and allow the user to choose the sorting via GET parameters; something like

```
http://mydomain.com/path/to/view/?sort=asc
```

Then in your view (this is very rough and should not be how you implement it):

```
def myview(request):
    ...
    # Check if the user has provided a 'sort' parameter, and check what it is
    if request.GET.get("sort", None) is "asc":
        results = SomeModel.objects.get(...).order_by("-name")
    ...
```

You can apply the same logic to filtering, although (in my opinion), if you are going to be changing the actual queryset (the objects returned), the filtering should be implemented through URLs, and not through GET parameters (which only effect the order in which the results are returned)